# JavaScript - How to loop through every row in every page in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I loop through every row in each page, not only the first page?

I am using DataTables v1.10.18 and I've managed to loop through the first 10 records, of the first page, but I could never get past the 1st page.

```
function loopThroughRows() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();

    table.rows().every(function () {
         var data = this.data();
    });
}
```

I've looked everywhere, tried many different examples, but it's still not working for me, maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your data loaded?  Is it paged server-side?

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgp1ybxk/) that runs your *exact* code that shows all rows are being referenced.   This is the correct way (ie don't reference the HTML), so if it's not working for you, there must be some other reason - such as the data is loaded page-by-page from the server (so not available in the UI).

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi, the data is loaded via the controller that returns a Json

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @freedomn-m I've found the issue in my case, the controller was bringing only the 10 records for the current page of the table, so the data was loaded page-by-page from the server, therefore it was not available in the UI.